# Can I scrape a single list that spans across multiple pages when webscraping with R?

Tags: r, web-scraping

Okay so I'm trying to scrape the table with dog temperaments from this website: https://atts.org/breed-statistics/statistics-page1/

However the table spans across 8 pages in total (and therefore 8 unique urls)

Currently, for page 1 of the table, I have written the following code:

```
url <- "https://atts.org/breed-statistics/statistics-page1/"

webpage <- read_html(url)

bn_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage, "td:nth-child(1)")
bn_data <- html_text(bn_data_html)

nt_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage, "td:nth-child(2)")
nt_data <- html_text(nt_data_html)

passed_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage, "td:nth-child(3)")
passed_data <- html_text(passed_data_html)

failed_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage, "td:nth-child(4)")
failed_data <- html_text(failed_data_html)

percent_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage, "td:nth-child(5)")
percent_data <- html_text(percent_data_html)

breeds <- data.frame(Breed = bn_data, Number_tested = nt_data, Passed = passed_data, Failed = failed_data, Percent = percent_data)
```

Which works wonderfully to scrape the data from the first page. However, in order to scrape the entire table, the only way I can think of to do it would be to replace the original url and rerun the chunk of code eight times for each page of the table. Is there a way to do this without having to rerun it eight times? Say the table spanned 100 pages and rerunning the code that many times just wasn't feasible?

Comment: You can search the page for a "next" link and follow that to the next page. But you'll have to write code to do that yourself. Every webpage is different in how it shares data. There's no universal way for `read_html` to understand that data is spread across page. You'll need to write your own loop that stops when it runs out of "next" links.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get them dogs into a dataframe, scraping `1:8` pages. Note the usage of `html_table()`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

get_dogs <- function(page) {
  str_c("https://atts.org/breed-statistics/statistics-page", page) %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_table() %>%
    getElement(1) %>%
    janitor::row_to_names(1) %>%
    janitor::clean_names()
  }

dogs_df <- map_dfr(1:8, get_dogs)

# A tibble: 250 x 5
   breed_name                 tested passed failed percent
   <chr>                      <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  
 1 AFGHAN HOUND               165    120    45     72.7%  
 2 AIREDALE TERRIER           110    86     24     78.2%  
 3 AKBASH DOG                 16     14     2      87.5%  
 4 AKITA                      598    465    133    77.8%  
 5 ALAPAHA BLUE BLOOD BULLDOG 12     9      3      75.0%  
 6 ALASKAN KLEE KAI           2      1      1      50.0%  
 7 ALASKAN MALAMUTE           244    207    37     84.8%  
 8 AMERICAN BANDAGGE          1      1      0      100.0% 
 9 AMERICAN BULLDOG           214    186    28     86.9%  
10 AMERICAN ESKIMO            86     71     15     82.6%  
# ... with 240 more rows
# i Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```